# How to increase the max size of response data nest C# library can handle?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We are using Nest calls to get the data from elastic search. But whenever the response body content length is more than 100mb we get out of memory exception.

1. Is there any limit on the response body size which Nest can handle?
2. Can we increase this limit size of response body?

Comment: are you sure this not your machine going out of memory trying to read the response? What type of program are you using to read the response?

Comment: can you provide a stack trace of the exceptions that you see? What version of NEST are you using? What version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?